# How to fix the any type in material ui Textfield

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I would like to understand once and for all how to fix the typescript error saying that na element has an any type and how to figure out how to actually figuring out what type I should be putting to solve my issues. Here's my simple code

```
import { MenuItem, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { Categories } from '../api/agent';
import { ICategory } from '../models/ApiInterface';

const CategorySelect = ({ handleCategoryChange }) => {
  const { data, isLoading, isError } = useQuery<ICategory[]>(
    ['categories'],
    Categories.list
  );

  if (isLoading) return;

  return (
    <TextField
      fullWidth
      label="Catégorie"
      name="cyberCategory"
      onChange={handleCategoryChange}
      select
      size="small"
      value={data}
    >
      {data?.map((category) => {
        return (
          <MenuItem key={category.id} value={category.name}>
            {category.name}
          </MenuItem>
        );
      })}
    </TextField>
  );
};

export { CategorySelect };
```

My error is with my **handleCategoryChange** in the props section of my arrow function. It's telling me that it has a any type and that I understand but what I would like to know is what to type there. I tried a couple of thing like React.ChangeEvent ... but I'm tired of trying random stuff i want to understand.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the "**Controlled vs Uncontrolled**" example of the MUI docs, you'll observe how to correctly define the change event handler:

```
  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const text = event.target.value;
    //some code to adapt the call to your "handleCategoryChange"
  };
```

Now, in your snippet is not clear how is the `CategorySelect` signature, so at most you'd have to adapt the input argument.

[Uncontrolled vs. Controlled :: MUI docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#uncontrolled-vs-controlled)